# Need Checkbutton with no checkmark AND flat border

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to create a Checkbutton with indicatoron = FALSE (meaning no indicator should be drawn) and relief = FLAT (meaning border should be normal and not standout from its environment. I can't seem to get both working at the same time. Is there any way around this? Example code below:

```
def create_buttons(self): 
    self.zerozeroButton = Checkbutton(self.frame_buttons, indicatoron = FALSE, text = "00", command = self.zerozero, relief = FLAT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the borderwidth to zero. Though, if you have no border and no indicator, I'm not sure how the user will know what the state of the widget is.

Or, perhaps you want the relief when selected but flat when deselected. If that is the case, leave the `borderwidth` and `relief` alone, but set `offrelief` to `FLAT`.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfect. Basically, I have decided to create a checkbutton that looks like a regular button so that I can manipulate its background color. Apparently, after much research, Macs do not have the ability to change the background color of a Button. However, Checkbuttons can change it. If you have an alternative I'd love to hear it.